# Slidable ListTile overlays parent in Flutter

Tags: list, flutter, listview, slide, shrinkwrap

It has some good features that I was looking for, and works with my code

I'm trying to make ToDo app, and I have problem with slidable widget. **I'm putting Slidable inside the ListTile element, and it appears to overlay the parent.** Actually, if I specify height of the parent list, it doesn't happen, but I can't specify the height of parent list, because it needs to be set automatically as new element is added to the list, this is why I use shrinkWrap property.

**EDIT:** I found package that does exactly what I need. It has some iOS-like slide features, and even some animations.

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_swipe_action_cell

```
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Column(
  children: [
    Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20),
      child: Container(
        child: ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            itemCount: this.widget.listNotes.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              var content = this.widget.listNotes[index];
              return Column(
                children: [
                  Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                    child: ListTile(
                      title: Container(
                        child: Slidable(
                          controller: slidableController,
                          actionPane: SlidableStrechActionPane(),
                          actionExtentRatio: 0.4,
                          secondaryActions: <Widget>[
                            SlideAction(
                              color: Colors.red,
                              child: Text(
                                'Delete',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 15, color: Colors.white),
                                maxLines: 1,
                              ),
                              onTap: () => deleteNote(index),
                            ),
                          ],
                          child: Row(
                            children: [
                              Container(
                                child: Transform.scale(
                                  scale: 1.7,
                                  child: Radio(
                                    toggleable: true,
                                    value: '${index}' + 'ok',
                                    groupValue: groupVal,
                                    onChanged: (value) {
                                      setState(() {
                                        groupVal = value;
                                      });
                                    },
                                    activeColor: Color(0xffFFBD11),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              InkWell(
                                onTap: () {
                                  print('object');
                                },
                                child: Container(
                                  width: 230,
                                  padding:
                                      EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 10, 12, 12),
                                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5),
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      border: Border(
                                          bottom: BorderSide(
                                              color: Color(0xFFBABABA),
                                              width: 0.5))),
                                  child: Text(
                                    content.note,
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.black,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                                        fontSize: 18),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              );
            }),
      ),
    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi @XRSIL your code is wrong, because the slidable widget must be the widget that contains the ListTile, like this example:

```
ListView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        itemCount: this.widget.listNotes.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) { 
            return Slidable(
                     actionPane: SlidableDrawerActionPane(),
                     child: Container(
                     child: ListTile(title: Text('Title'),
                   ),
                  ));
            }
         )
```

Comment: Thank you, but I also found another solution

Comment: If you see that this library https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_slidable has more reputation, that means it is used by more developers and the community can help you if you have a problem